# Problema com query mysql, qual seria a melhor forma de resolver

Tags: mysql, sql, query, select

Olá, eu estou tentando fazer uma consulta para um sistema de pedidos para um restaurante. Minhas tabelas estão dispostas da seguinte forma:

[image: Tabelas]

Eu preciso trazer todas as mesas (independente se elas possuem ou não pedido) caso elas possuam pedido com status 0 esses pedidos devem vir. Caso não exista pedido(s) com status 0 para aquela determinada mesa, o pedido deve vir null.

**Por exemplo**:

Tables:

```
[1,1]
[2,1]
[3,1]
[4,1]
```

Orders:

```
[1,1,0]
[2,2,1]
[3,3,1]
[4,4,0]
[5,4,1]
[6,3,-1]
[7,2,0]
```

Resultado esperado:

```
Table.id | Order.id 
1        |1
2        |null
3        |null
4        |4
2        |7
```

Comment: Pesquise por outer join https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/outer-join-simplification.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o comparador `IF`, [veja clicando aqui.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT tables.id as `TableID`, IF(orders.status = 0, orders.id, null) as `OrderID` FROM tables LEFT JOIN orders ON tables.id = orders.table_id
```

Dessa forma irá retornar o `id` se o `orders.status` for justamente o `0` e irá retornar `null` se o `orders.status` for diferente do `0`.

---

Você também pode adicionar esta condição no `LEFT JOIN`, por exemplo, [recomendo que leia isso para mais informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join):

```
SELECT tables.id as `TableID`, pedido.id as `OrderID` FROM tables LEFT JOIN orders ON tables.id = orders.table_id AND orders.status = 0
```

Isso *iria juntar* as tabelas quando o `tables.id` for igual ao `tabled_id` e também que o `status` for `0`. Fora desta condição as tabelas não seriam *juntadas*, assim iria apenas retornar os dados da `tables` enquanto o restante, correspondente ao `orders`, teriam o valor de `null`.

Comment: Opa cara, resolveu! Só mais uma coisinha... E se eu quisesse trazer todos os dados da tabela orders? Além do id. (Com a mesma regra, se não existir pedido com status 0, o pedido inteiro deve vir nulo)

Comment: Por padrão usando `LEFT JOIN` ele irá retornar `null` no que não houver o dado, por isso poderia utilizar `ON tables.id = orders.table_id AND orders.status = 0`, assim o que não for igual a `0` seria null.  De qualquer forma pode utilizar o  `IF(pedido.status = 0, pedido.UmColuna, null) as UmaColuna`, isso iria retornar o valor de `UmaColuna` ou `null`.

Comment: Muito obrigado cara! Ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 0):

Use: [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

```
IFNULL(expr1, null)
```

**No seu caso ficaria assim:**

```
SELECT tables.id as `TableID`, IFNULL(pedido.status, null) 
as `OrderID` 
FROM tables LEFT JOIN orders ON tables.id = orders.table_id
```

Obs:A substituição de null pode ser por qualquer outro valor, não necessariamente string.

**Da documentação:**

> Se expr1 não for NULL, IFNULL () retorna expr1; Caso contrário retorna
>   expr2. IFNULL () retorna um valor numérico ou seqüência de caracteres,
>   dependendo do contexto em que ele é usada.